# How to create a zip of zip of a list in python. I need it for a double for loop

Tags: python, list, python-zip

I have the following lists:

```
mylist1 = ["peru", "germany", "japan"]
mylist2 = [["lima","cusco"], ["berlin","munich"], ["tokyo"]]
mylist3=[[1,2],[3,4],[5]]
```

and I want to print

```
peru
lima
1
cusco
2

germany
berlin
3
munich
4

japan
tokyo
5
```

One zip command looks like:

```
list=list(zip(mylist1,mylist2,mylist3))

for country,cities,nums in list:
    print(country)
    for city in cities:
         print(city)
    for num in nums:
         print(num)
```

But as you can guess, it won't output what I want. So I thought of a double zip like
`list = list(zip(mylist1,zip(mylist2,mylist3)))`, and then

```
for country,info in list:
    print(country)
    for city,num in info:
         print(city)
         print(num)
```

But it doesn't work. I do need 2 for loops. One for the country and a second one to handle the other info.

Comment: _I do need 2 for loops.  One for the country and a second one to handle the other info_ Sounds like you already know exactly what you need.  So.... what is your question??

Comment: I was missing how to call zip in the second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using three zips in total, although you can do it in a simpler way if you use indices with enumerate (assuming the lists have the same length):

```
mylist1 = ["peru", "germany", "japan"]
mylist2 = [["lima","cusco"], ["berlin","munich"], ["tokyo"]]
mylist3 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5]]

for country, (cities, numbers) in zip(mylist1, zip(mylist2, mylist3)):
    print(country)
    for city, number in zip(cities, numbers):
        print(city)
        print(number)
```